# anyone attempted a multiple p2sh(multisig) send (ideally using python)?

Tags: python, pybitcointools, pycoin

I attempted to use [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) to do a "create_signed_tx" in python, but had no joy: Do you think it might be technically possible to use spendables(UTXOs) from **multiple** source P2SH wallets in a single push to the network ? Anyone done this successfully yet(ideally using python)?

Comment: what is a "multiple source p2sh wallet"?

Comment: sorry if that was unclear: I mean sending bitcoin from "more than one" P2SH wallet in one transaction(push) transmit. By saying "multiple source" I didn't imply a special case. P2SH(pay to script hash) is like a multisig wallet(most "multisig" transactions these days are actually P2SH). Multisig wallet: one where more than one private key is required to spend coins.

Answer (score 1):

answer is yes, its possible: I was merely doing it wrong in my earlier attempt(s):
have posted a gist to illustrate how I got it working using a few python libraries on the testnet: https://gist.github.com/kumrzz/111f8ea12af3528f496cbe678d153fc0